# Highcharts Export after updating colorAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When using Highcharts heapmap module, there is an issue with exporting the chart following a `colorAxis` update.

I create a chart using

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    ...
    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },
    ...
})
```

Following an `update` on the `colorAxis`, where `max` is altered, an export of the chart shows the original scale.

Is there something I should be doing differently?

[Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/garrettascott/rje8y2sw/)

Comment: Will you be changing a lot of different values after creating the chart, or just `colorAxis.max` in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. Looks like this is an issue with how Highcharts handles the update of the colorAxis. It doesn't set the `chart.options.colorAxis` values correctly.

In the update call, the following line (line 15467 in highcharts.src.js) is supposed to update the correct `chart.options` value.

```
newOptions = chart.options[this.coll][this.options.index] = merge(this.userOptions, newOptions);
```

However, `chart.options.colorAxis` is not an array and doesn't have `this.options.index`. Thus, this line doesn't work as intended. This can be fixed if you slightly modify to check if the index exists and update either the object or the indexed object as necessary.

```
newOptions = this.options.index ? chart.options[this.coll][this.options.index] : chart.options[this.coll] = merge(this.userOptions, newOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call your action in the chart callback, and wrap exporting into setTimeout(), then will work.

```
    chart.colorAxis[0].update({
        max: 200
    }, true);
    setTimeout(function () {
        chart.exportChart();
    }, 1);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rje8y2sw/6/

Comment: This works if you know beforehand what you want your colorAxis to be, as is the case with my simplified jsFiddle example. However, if it changes dynamically at user defined times, this solution doesn't work.